# shared_ptr scope basic understanding

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

Hi I am new to C++11 concepts. I have declared two shared pointer with difference scope. I am assigning local scope to one step higher scope shared_ptr. I am trying to print the same. Its not causing any problem. Of course i do agree our normal pointer also have the same property. But that might end up with dangling pointer. Here I just want to know whether sPtr2 pointing to invalid pointer or else its proper.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
struct MyStruct_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
int main() {
shared_ptr<MyStruct_t> sPtr2;
if(1)
{

    shared_ptr<MyStruct_t> sPtr1 (new MyStruct_t);
    sPtr1->a = 5;
    sPtr1->b = 10;
    sPtr2 = sPtr1;
    cout<<"sPtr1->a : "<<sPtr1->a<<" b value : "<<sPtr1->b<<endl;
    cout<<"sPtr1 address is : "<<sPtr1<<endl;
}
cout<<"sPtr2->a : "<<sPtr2->a<<" b value : "<<sPtr2->b<<endl;
cout<<"sPtr2 Address is : "<<sPtr2<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's proper. ..

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks.

Comment: You don't actually need `if(1)` here. `{ }` can be used directly to create a scope where an instruction is expected.